# AWS mysql.rds_set_external_master and autocommit

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, master-slave

I am setting up an RDS MySQL 5.6 database as a slave to an external master. I run this

```
CALL mysql.rds_set_external_master(...);
CALL mysql.rds_start_replication;
```

With respect to rds_set_external_master, AWS says **"To run this procedure, autocommit must be enabled.**" https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/mysql_rds_set_external_master.html

But can I set autocommit to off once I have started it with rds_start_replication? Or must autocommit be on for the whole time that it is a slave?

What if I do rds_stop_replication and rds_start_replication again (but without running rds_set_external_master again)?

I am asking because I will be switching the slave over to the production environment where autocommit must be off. It would be nice if I could have all the parameters set correctly before making the switch so I don't have to take the extra time to modify the DB and reboot it during the downtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, I switched autocommit to off and it worked just fine. Maybe that's because the slave database was a regular DB, not one that was read-only, as AWS suggests.